# How I can test a webapp written in Play framework?

Tags: playframework

How I can test a web app written in Play framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very easily. The documentation is a good place to start.

http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.2/test

Take a look at this documentation, and if there is anything that doesn't make sense, raise another question.